# How to remove an appendChild element in JS

Tags: javascript

So basically, I want to remove the appendChild element once it has been clicked. I tried to use this.remove(), but it does not work. I manually added some divs with h2 inside of it. When I clicked the div then, my code worked. When I clicked it, it did go away.

## Code snippet

```js
var div_children = document.getElementById("append-div").children;
            var length = div_children.length;
            for (var x = 0; x < length; x++){
                div_children[x].addEventListener("click", function(){
                    this.remove();
                });
            }
            function myfunction(){
                var new_div = document.createElement("DIV");
                new_div.innerHTML = "<h2>New div</h2>";
                document.getElementById("append-div").appendChild(new_div);
            }
```

```css
#append-div{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#append-div div{
    background-color: lightblue;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    border-radius: 45px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width:fit-content;
    height:fit-content;
}
#append-div div h2{
    margin:20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <link = rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="styles.css">
            <title>Test</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <button class = "click-me" onclick = "myfunction()">Click Me!</button>
            <div id = "append-div"></div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: There are already solutions below so I will just explain to you why it exactly doesn't work. Try to `console.log(length)` right after you declare it. It's always 0 because this function is invoked when there are no added elements. Without event listener, there is no way that JS knows that you added element to the DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you were having before in the removal is that the first part of the code runs without any children and it never runs again even after you create new ones.

---

There's no need to loop through the children to add the event listener.

Just add it to the child right after you create the element.

```js
function myfunction() {
  var new_div = document.createElement("DIV");
  new_div.innerHTML = "<h2>New div</h2>";
  new_div.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.remove();
  });
  document.getElementById("append-div").appendChild(new_div);
  
}
```

```css
#append-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#append-div div {
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border-radius: 45px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
}

#append-div div h2 {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button class="click-me" onclick="myfunction()">Click Me!</button>
<div id="append-div"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this

```
document.getElementById("append-div").outerHTML = "";
```

It has support on cross browsers & IE 11+

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML

Comment: That would clear entire `div`. I think the author only meant removing clicked elements.

Comment: It will only remove that element & replace it with an empty string

Comment: This element you mean the `#append-div` which has an unfortunate name but stores all of the new elements.

Answer (score 0):

you could add the listener event when is created the element, as below:

```js
function myfunction() {
  var new_div = document.createElement("DIV");
  new_div.innerHTML = "<h2>New div</h2>";
  new_div.onclick = function () {
    this.remove()
  }
  document.getElementById("append-div").appendChild(new_div);
}
```

```html
<button class = "click-me" onclick = "myfunction()">Click Me!</button>
<div id = "append-div"></div>
```